# What is your must have or recommend extensions?

Tags: extensions, module

When I read Fabian Blechschmidt's [this interview](http://www.cloudways.com/blog/fabian-blechschmidt-interview/), I'm so surprise I know only one extension (Aoe_Scheduler) among he recommend 5 extensions. I never hear rest of 4 extensions before

So I realize there should be a lot of good extensions I don't know or use.

**What is your must have or recommend Magento extensions?**

Answer (score 0):

That's so different from shop to shop or user to user.

There are modules for performance, marketing, etcetera. Then you have different sites, b2b, b2c, mobile... All with specific needs...

Besides, everyone has his own set of preferred modules!
You are starting a discussion which I do not think is a real question, it is rather something for a forum.

Comment: I agree your point. But I believe this kind of info could help people. Like you said, Is there any forum I can discuss this kind of topic?

Comment: I visited some real life usergroups to discuss these things. Also use Google for some specific topics (like performance, marketing) try some and find out which suits you best. People wrote a lot about specific topics in blogs

Answer (score -1):

Some of the best must-have Magento extensions are as follows :

**Google Enhanced Ecommerce for Magento (Free)**
To help make Universal Analytics and Enhanced Ecommerce integration quicker and easier      for Magento shop owners

**Subscriptions and Recurring Payments (Paid)**
The Subscriptions and Recurring Payments extension was designed for Magento shop owners who sell products or services based on a subscription (e.g. magazines, licenses, groceries, medication).

**Klarna Payment Extension (Free)**
It will help increase conversions and includes invoice and part payment options, which collects a buyer’s purchases into one monthly invoice that can be paid in full or in installments. Klarna makes checkout simple for your customers with no forced registration process.

**Product Reviews (Free or Paid)**
This extension is brilliant in that it allows shop owners to customize the reviews display and even lets you customize and brand the emails sent to the reviewers after they've submitted a review.